# How to ignore files over two hours from a timestamp range in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to set up a timestamp range for a file that is not over 2 hours in Perl.  Taking times from file are formatted as "May 26 20:30 filename.csv" in perl format.

Here is what I am setting up:

```
use File::stat;
my $stat = stat($file);

# To start a time within a range or no more than 2 hours
my $start = UnixDate("now", "%m%d %H:%M"); 
my $stop = UnixDate("$start"+2, "%m%d %H:%M");  // here max it to 2 hours, not sure this part
if ($stat->$start <= $stat->$stop) { next; }
```

Comment: Does `UnixDate` return an epoch time stamp? If so, just compare against `time - 2*60*60`

Comment: Yes it returns an epoch time, how do I fix that block of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that `UnixDate` returns an epoch timestamp, all you need is this:

```perl
my $cutoff = time - 2*60*60;

my $file_time = UnixDate( "%m%d %H:%M", $fn );
next if $file_time < $cutoff;
```

Comment: which import are you using for time? just double checking if its from Date::Manip or thats the `time` of the system? sorry double ck.

Comment: $fn you are referring as the file name?

Comment: `time` is a Perl function/operator. And yes, the file name.